Question flagged and closed as a duplicate of its own Staging Ground post
This question has received several duplicate flags for this Staging Ground post and was closed as a duplicate of that post in Staging Ground. This is odd, since the latter is the SG version of that same question.
Testing on other posts revealed that SG posts generally can't be duplicate targets:

Given that, how did this occur?

I don't know how that happened, but the question definitely should not be open. It's barely coherent, it isn't at all clear how the OP expects the code to work etc. If the goal really is just to have non-blocking read of standard input, that's surely a duplicate, but I also can't fathom what's intended to happen inside the loop when input hasn't been received yet.

If you search by post id instead of the full URL (at least as a mod) it's very happy to give you the post in Staging Ground (screenshot). There definitely should be a post-type check added to that query and not just rely on using a /staging-ground/ url.

There is an exception which allows unanswered questions to be used as duplicate targets if the author of both posts is the same. I'm not sure if a regular user would normally be able to use a staging ground post as a dupe target, I would expect it to fail simply due to it not having any answers. So it's possible this is a very specific edge case and was simply overlooked. That said, closing a post of a duplicate of itself creates a stalemate. The post in Staging Ground can't be published again, the duplicate closure on the main site is absurd and likely frustrating for the asker.

Well, what shouldn't be allowed, is that when Users have a Qt (Question) in the 'Staging Ground' (in New Require [major-minor] changes Re-evaluate State), those Users shouldn't be allowed to open new Qt's (bypassing the SG)...

It turns out that by manipulating the URL of a SG post and changing /staging-ground/ to /q/, it is possible to designate it as a duplicate target. I was able to do so for this SG question, which was an exact duplicate of another SG question asked by the same user.
Whether or not this is intended behavior, I don't know. Being able to target an SG question from the main site is definitely wrong, so it seems like the rules around targeting self-dupes need some tweaking.

I think this didn't work during the beta as the SG post didn't have an answer but I think this restriction was removed for posts from the same user in order to deal with someone asking the same question multiple times skipping the Staging Ground.

@dan1st I was thinking the same thing. There should probably be a check for whether the SG post has graduated or something.

If the same user asks multiple posts in the SG, it also makes sense to close one as a duplicate of the other.
