How should I flag a question that is a repost of a Staging Ground question that hasn't graduated?
A user posted this question which went to Staging Ground. There isn't nearly enough information to answer it, and some comments were left suggesting needed changes. The poster then posted the same question again; apparently rewritten, but still not really comprehensible. This one went directly to the main site. It looks like the user created a new account to do this.
How should such questions be flagged? I unsuccessfully tried to flag the second post as a dupe following this advice.

The same as any other kind of repost: "hi mods, this is a repost of... Please delete"

Why would you close the main site post as a duplicate of the SG post? You ideally should be doing it the other way round (If needed a close vote on main site as well)

@AbdulAzizBarkat -- I don't understand why you would think to close the SG post as a duplicate of the (later) main site post, a post which was made by circumventing the Staging Ground system. I did vote to close on the main site as well.

@adabsurdum SG posts aren't published yet, which means their visibility is limited to users who can review and the author. Closing as a duplicate of a post in SG is going to result in a confusing situation.

@AbdulAzizBarkat -- agreed, which is why I posted this question.

To be honest, I'm not sure whether it's better to flag posts like that or to just mark the SG post as a duplicate of the other one and include a comment saying they shouldn't post the same question multiple times. Is there anything mods do apart from deleting one of the post if the user doesn't do it repeatedly?

@dan1st "It looks like the user created a new account to do this." -> that makes it a little bit more than a first offender deal, so I would say this case does not really compare to others :)

take a hammer and weaponize https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431216/11107541 (<- this is a joke)

@Gimby I didn't notice multiple accounts used for that but yes, for that I would also flag it.

"I unsuccessfully tried to flag the second post as a dupe following this advice." Because it's a different account, it wouldn't have worked; that advice only works when the post is also posted by the same user account. Posts in the SG can't have answers, so it's impossible for them to be the target of a duplicate vote unless the 2 posts are by the same user (as the target doesn't have any answers that are either accepted or have a score >= 1).

@Dharman is it required to greet mods? ;)

Only because you can't salute in a flag message, @M--. (But in all seriousness, no. Definitely don't start your flags with "hi mods" or anything else like that. I mean, we won't get mad, but it's pointless and unnecessary. The character limit is already extremely, frustratingly short, so you shouldn't waste space with wastes of space. And it's just noise for us that slows us down as we're scanning through the list of flags.)

In lieu of other answers I'll go ahead and self-answer based on the comment from @Dharman.
Raise a moderator flag and suggest deletion of the question on the main site. This is in alignment with how we usually handle other instances of a user reposting one of their questions.
